# Spring Autowired gwt RemoteServiceServlet implement class is null

Tags: java, spring, gwt, autowired

I have two gwt RemoteServiceServlet in my project which has use GWT framework as below

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("AuthService")
public interface AuthService extends RemoteService {
}

public class AuthServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements AuthService
{
     @Autowired
     private StoredService storeService;
}

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("webService")
public interface WebService extends RemoteService
{
}

public class WebServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements WebService
{
     @Autowired
     private LogService logService;
}
```

Both the @Autowired of StoreService and LogService are work. But when I try to autowired WebService in AuthService, it will be null at runtime.

The interface and implements are in different package, which is com.test.client.service and com.test.server.service respectively.

I have confirm my SpringApplication-context.xml has below declare:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.test.client.service, com.test.server.service
>
```

Also try to add @Service, @Component or @Configurable on WebServiceImpl, but still not works.

Override the init() of WebServiceImpl is also not work either.

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext())
        .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
}
```

Is that because the RemoteService cause the autowired not work correctly?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to integrate GWT-RPC into Spring. I wrote it 6 years ago and never saw the need to change it. It is old-school and it works. It models GWT-RPC services as Spring MVC controllers, which they are. You can autowire anything into those controllers.

I mentioned it in a different answer, so I'll just post a link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30838630/4982193